# SPRESENSE と拡張ボードを格納する筐体を探しております

Tags: spresense

アプリ開発の場ですが、迷ってしまってます。お知恵をお貸しください。

弊社では、位置情報を提供するサービスをしており、今回SONYのSPRESENSE と拡張ボードを格納する筐体を探しております。選挙カーなどに乗せて位置情報を取得し。LTE通信でサーバにビックデータとして格納しようとしております。次のような筐体を考えた場合、ベストは何でしょうか。お教えくださいませ。

1. 防水にしたい。
2. 電源は非接触充電で、測位のON/OFFや周期と送信タイミングをボタン等では無く、非接触等で指示できる様にしたい。
3. 大きさは、カロリーメイトの箱くらいにしたい。
4. バッテリーを内蔵したい。
5. 自動車に据え置きできる取り付け具も必要。

Comment: 質問の内容に「どこの誰か (会社名)」は不要ですし、余計なトラブル等を避けるためにも削らせてもらいました。

Comment: 既製品として存在しないなら、業者への依頼も含めて3Dプリントでの自作等になりそうです。[ケースの自作例](https://elchika.com/article/d9158fa1-8d54-4bfe-b589-b75af7f266e9/#h_%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E6%BA%96%E5%82%99)

Comment: コンシューマー向けを考えています。製品として販売したいので、一品ものはコストがかかりすぎて悩んでます。ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 製品として販売するのであれば、タッパーなんぞは問題外となります
プラスチックの成形やさんに行って独自で防水ケースを作ろう、ってことにしかなりませんが。

Answer (score 5):

スタックオーバーフローに質問するような内容かな？とは思いますが、一応知見を共有します。

SPRESENSEに限らず、屋外用のセンサーシステムのPoCで、私はよくタッパーを活用します。防水はばっちりですし、いろいろな大きさが選べます。タッパーにあわせて３Dプリントで内部に固定用治具をつくっておけば一応それらしい形になります。

悩ましいのはカメラや太陽光パネル等からの給電の配線で、穴をあけないといけません。どうしても隙間ができてしまいます。その場合は、日曜大工などで使われるコーキング剤やグルーなどで穴を埋めておけば、一応防水らしいことはできます。（うまく塗る腕が必要ですが）

DIYersの方々は、タッパーを活用している方々が多くいますので、「電子工作　タッパー」ググってみるといろいろな作例が見れると思いますよ。

以上ご参考になれば。

Comment: みなさんいろいろ工夫されていること理解しました。試作段階ではタッパーでも良さそうですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 製品用の筐体をお探しなんですね。スタックオーバーフローで紹介するのもちょっとどうかなとも思いますが、個人的にはタカチ電気工業さんの製品を使うのがよいと思います。色々な種類のケースがありますし、カスタマイズにも対応しています。ご参考になれば。https://www.takachi-el.co.jp/

Answer (score 0):

防水ケース、防水筐体、などでぐぐると、いろいろでてきますよ。